# Accessing 3rd part hardware in cordova/android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, phonegap

I just got this android device that has a thermal printer. It also comes with a SDK that has an external `.jar` file that can be used to communicate with the device.

Now I am trying to print text from javascript to the device. In the samples they have given for java projects you can print using the following:

```
import com.nbbse.printer.Printer;
public static Printer print;
print = Printer.getInstance();
print.printText(“Printer testing!!!”);
print.printText(“Printer testing!!!”, 3);
print.printText(“Printer testing!!!”, true);
print.printText("Printer Testing!!!", 2, false);
```

How can I achieve the same in a cordova application?
I have started by adding the `.jar` in the `libs` folder and then including this line in the `config.xml`:

```
<lib-file src="platforms/android/libs/MP3_Api_V0.6.jar"/>
```

How can I invoke the printing directly from a javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a cordova-plugin to actually use the native library. You can find the plugin development guide [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html).

You will have to move your `<lib-file>` tag from `config.xml` to the `plugin.xml` of your plugin. I also think you did put the `.jar` directly into the android platform folder. You should never directly modify this folder as it is recreated/modified on build.
You can put the `.jar` file in a subfolder of your plugin and reference it like that in `plugin.xml` (if you name the subfolder `libs`):

```
<lib-file src="libs/MP3_Api_V0.6.jar"/>
```

The docs for this are [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html#adding-dependency-libraries).